# SQL Reporting Services empty string handling

Tags: sql, string, reporting, service

I'd like to display a string without the last 2 chars in a text field in Reporting Services 2005 vs2005.
I tried several ways and if the string is empty or null I get an error:
rsRuntimeErrorInExpression - The value expression for the textbox contains an error: Argument 'Length' must be greater or equal to zero.

Here are the ways I tried:
IIF(trim(Fields!kuku.Value) = "","", Left(Fields!kuku.Value, Len(Fields!kuku.Value) - 2))

IIF(IsNothing(Fields!kuku.Value) and Len(Fields!kuku.Value) = 0,"",Left(Fields!kuku.Value, Len(Fields!kuku.Value) - 2))

IIF(IsNothing(Fields!kuku.Value) ,"",Left(Fields!kuku.Value, Len(Fields!kuku.Value) - 2))

IIF(Len(Fields!kuku.Value) = 0,"",Left(Fields!kuku.Value, Len(Fields!kuku.Value) - 2))

Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

how about changing the dataset on that field to use isnull(field,", ") that way you can always safely trim 2 characters.

or

```
IIF(IsNothing(Fields!kuku.Value) OR Len(Fields!kuku.Value) < 2,"",Left(Fields!kuku.Value, Len(Fields!kuku.Value) - 2))
```

note the *and* changed to an *OR*. And just in case the length is 1 changed  `=0` to `<2`